# Cocos2d, I forgot what the command was for delaying a scene

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

I want the game over scene to not show up for a few seconds so you can actually see how you died. I remember doing this a while back but I can not remember for the life of me.

```
        GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene node];
        [gameOverScene.layer.label setString:@"You Lose"];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameOverScene];
```

Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not getting what exactly you need. Still suggesting these two..try

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showGameOverScene) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0f];
```

Replace with time:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[GameOverScene scene] withColor:ccWHITE]];
```

Comment: this seems like it would work but I get the error + scene not found

Comment: @user1543821 hmm, ok use [GameOverScene node] inplace of [GameOverScene scene].

Answer (score 1):

Use NSObject's `[self performSelector:@selector(gameOver) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];` and replace the scene in the new method GameOver:

```
- (void)gameOver
{
    GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene node];
    [gameOverScene.layer.label setString:@"You Lose"];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameOverScene];
}
```

Comment: wait is  [self performSelector:@selector(gameOver) withObject:nil afterDelay:5]; the actual command?

Comment: Its a method from NSObject so every object has it

Answer (score 0):

A solution may be to schedule a selector to do your actions:

```
[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] scheduleSelector:@selector(myMethod:) forTarget:self interval:2.0f paused:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] isPaused]];
```

And your method implementation:

```
- (void)myMethod:(ccTime)dt
{
    [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] unscheduleSelector:_cmd forTarget:self];

    //your actions here
    GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene node];
    [gameOverScene.layer.label setString:@"You Lose"];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameOverScene];
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think it will work if  this wasn't a void  method, but i believe you are on the right track.